# Deleting from database, unsuccessful

Tags: android

I am trying to delete an entry from a database have been unsuccessful.  Here is my code to show what I am doing. I create a `ContextMenu`, which opens a new menu titled "Delete" but when I click on this delete it doesn't delete the selected item. It just doesn't do anything.

main.java:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class Announce extends ListActivity{
    private CommentsDataSource datasource;
    EditText edit;      


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.announce);

        datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();      

        List<Comment> values = datasource.getAllComments();

        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Comment>) getListAdapter();
        Comment comment = null;
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:  
            edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxt);            
            Editable txt=(Editable)edit.getText();
            String insert = txt.toString();         
            comment = datasource.createComment(insert);
            adapter.add(comment);
            edit.setText("");
            break;      
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();          
        if(item.getTitle() == "Delete") {
            datasource.deleteCommentById(info.id);          
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        datasource.open();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        datasource.close();
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

And here is my SQLHelper, which I am calling for delete.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class CommentsDataSource {

    // Database fields
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT };

    public CommentsDataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public Comment createComment(String comment) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT, comment);
        long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, null,
                values);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
                allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Comment newComment = cursorToComment(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newComment;
    }

    public void deleteComment(Comment comment) {
        long id = comment.getId();
        System.out.println("Comment deleted with id: " + id);
        database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
    }

    public void deleteCommentById(long id) {
        System.out.println("Comment deleted with id: " + id);
        database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
    }

    public List<Comment> getAllComments() {
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
                allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
            comments.add(comment);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // Make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return comments;
    }

    private Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        comment.setComment(cursor.getString(1));
        return comment;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It just simply does not delete the item I choose.

Comment: In case my answer doesn't help, have you tried setting breakpoints and debugging this code? If so, how far does it get? Does it hit onContextItemSelected in the Annouce activity? Does it reach the deleteCommentById method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should call this

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after this part of code..

```
  datasource.deleteCommentById(info.id);
```

Comment: Probably yes, but when i type it shows up as error i try: info.notifyDataSetChanged(); and it shows as fixed add cast to info but this is not helping.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
if(item.getTitle() == "Delete") {
```

to

```
if(item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
```

Comment: Tryed nothing happens. It seem thath it doesnt even recognize thath item was clicked..

Comment: Are you saying that the onContextItemSelected method is never called?

Comment: Dont know if its called or not as i am not realy familiar with this debugger in eclipse, But i tryed chaning methoid little bit but nothing happens.